# google maps traffic layer with a specific timestamp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Anyone knows if there is a possibility to get the Google Maps traffic layer  for specific timestamps like 09.01.2015 14:15? Using Anuglar1 & Google Maps Api.

This is how I set the traffic layer. Maybe I can set anywhere some options?

```
var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
                trafficLayer.setMap(map);
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Is there really no way in the meantime? Even not with an API key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not according to the docs:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/trafficlayer

> Traffic information is provided for the time at which the request is
>   made.